# Cannot connect my Google account on an iPhone 5 / iOS 10.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail

I have a new iPhone 5 and I tried to connect to my Google account, but without success.

I first open the *Accounts* view:

[image]

When clicking on *Google*, the *OAuth* view appears and I enter my email/password.

I immediately receive a security alert on my *Gmail* indicating that a new device is trying to connect to my account. I click *Check my activity* and confirm that I'm at the origin of this connection.

Unfortunately, my iPhone goes back to the *Accounts* view without adding my gmail account to the list.

Comment: Have you tried setting it up as "Other?" Sometimes entering the server info manually works better. All of that is available in Gmail help.